# How to get a fixed number of delays through arduino in a stepper motor?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, uistepper

I have to stop the stepper motor certain number of times (for one complete rotation) with delays as the stopping parameters.Suppose my requirement is  to stop the motor 20 number of times so that my delay value should be evenly distributed between this number (20) for complete one rotation.I used a for loop for these stops(20) but i get delys more than 20.My code for arduino is given below where 8000 are the number of steps in one revolution:

```
    #include <Stepper.h>

    const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
    // for your motor

    // initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
    Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);

    void setup() {
    // set the speed at 60 rpm:
    myStepper.setSpeed(60);
    // initialize the serial port:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    }

   // step one revolution  in one direction:
   void loop() {
   int noi=20;// set the no of images here
   for(int i=0;i<=noi;i++){
    delay(8000/noi);
    }
    Serial.println("clockwise");
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);

    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want the code to do. Please re-word the question. Right now, the loop() delays for 8 seconds, then turns the motor once. The variable `noi` does nothing.

Comment: actually we have made a platform which will rotate according to the  steps of stepper motor.We will keep the object on this platform and take images(20) of the same by rotating it 20 times (or any number) to cover full 360 degree. How should i set the delay value so that whole 360 degree is covered for the 20 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still confusing, but more clear than before.

It looks like you have a stepper motor that drives a turntable. The motor takes 200 steps for one revolution, but it takes 8000 steps to turn the turntable one revolution.

In one sense, all that matters is the number 8000. To make the table pause, you need to divide 8000 into equal pieces, as it looks like you attempted. But you have misplaced a `}`.

```
void loop() {
    int noi=20;// set the no of images here
    for(int i=0;i<=noi;i++){
        delay(8000/noi);
    } <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< REMOVE
    Serial.println("clockwise");
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);

} 

void loop() {
    int noi=20;// set the no of images here
    for(int i=0;i<=noi;i++){
        delay(enough_delay_to_take_image);  // or trigger image here?
        Serial.println("clockwise");
        myStepper.step(8000/noi);
    }   
}
```

The only place that `stepsPerRevolution = 200` matters is in calculating the speed of the movement, along with `myStepper.setSpeed(60);`. Do you really wanting the table to move that quickly? It might cause the object to shake too much.

```
      myStepper.setSpeed(1);
```

will cause the movements betyween images to take 3 seconds. If that is too slow,

```
      myStepper.setSpeed(3);
```

will cause the movements betyween images to take 1 second.